# How to Extract Numbers From a Polynomial String (including the + and - signs)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to extract e.g. `-13`, as a negative value out of a polynomial, e.g. `-13x^2+2-12x^4`. So far, I've successfully take out the powers. Additionally, my solution came up to this:

```
 /\(+)(-)\d{1,4}/g
```

I know it's wrong syntax, but I'm not sure how to represent the `+` or `-` which goes with the following number.
It would be good if you can show me how to count the next `x` like the end of an common/searched phrase, I'm not sure about the term. You know, if it is -3x^ and the point is to extract `-3`, then it should be like `/\ + or - \/d{1,4} x_here/g`

Comment: @zerkms does it depend on whether I use the new RegExp() class, or the normal = /things/ pattern, because now it looks like this:

  sc = str_input.match`(/(+|-)\d{1,4}/g)`  an points out for an error... invalid syntax, indeed

Comment: @zerkms I've actually removed the + from (+|-), making it (|-) and it works

Comment: @KDX2 also don't forget that `(\+|-)` will create a backreference, which might be unwanted. In that case, use `(?:\+|-)` instead. `?:` is for "non-capturing group" and thus won't create a backreference.

Comment: @zerkms , sorry for that but, how can I take just the coeficients, which means, how should I count `x` as an end of searched phrase? P.S. I've put it up my way, for those who are interested - here is the line ->
`/[+-]?\d{1,4}[x]/g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var formula = '-13x^2+2-12x^4';

formula.match(/[+-]?\d{1,4}/g);
```

Returns:

```
["-13", "2", "+2", "-12", "4"]
```

If you wish to organize the numbers into coefficients and powers, here's an approach that works:

```
var formula = '-13x^2+2-12x^4';

function processMatch(matched){
    var arr = [];
    matched.forEach(function(match){
        var vals = match.split('^');
        arr.push({
            coeff: parseInt(vals[0]),
            power: vals[1] != null ? parseInt(vals[1]) : 0
        })
    })
    console.log(arr);
}

processMatch(formula.match(/[+-]?\d+x\^\d+|[+-\s]\d[+-\s]/g))

/* console output:
var arr = [
    { coeff: -13, power: 2 },
    { coeff: 2, power: 0 },
    { coeff: -12, power: 4 }        
];*/
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want:

```
var str = '2x^2-14x+5';
var re = /([+-]?\d{1,4})/g;
var result = str.match(re);
```